# How can i mock auth0 authentication for testing?

Tags: node.js, auth0, express-jwt

I am using [autho0](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js) and [express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) in order to authenticate my app users.

Everything is really cool besides the tests. 
The content that i pass in my API is strictly partitioned by authors. This means you can only access a content if you own it.

I am using `req.user.sub` (wich is provided by jwt if the user is recognized) to set the author of the content that  is being passed in my API.

Should i use req.user.name to provide the author ? If so, how can i mock the authentication in order to write my tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a simple solution which is a bit rudimentary:

```
public static testAuthorName = 'test-author';
private static getAuthor(req) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
        return MyApiClass.testAuthorName;
    }
    return req.user.sub.split('|')[1];
}
```

This way i can just use `MyApiClass.testAuthorName`statically in my tests.