# How to mock an auth0 user for Playwright testing?

Tags: vuejs3, auth0, playwright

Previously we handled all auth0 logic manually, saving user info in cookies, handling all the refreshing logic by ourselves, etc. Now we switched to auth0-vue since we migrated to vue 3, but we have e2e test where we need to test new user flow and previously we could just replace cookie and call it a day - no need to create a new user each time. But now, when all the auth logic happens under the hood of the plugin, it became quite impossible to do it the same way. But we don’t want to register a new user every time and make unnecessary clutter and definetely don't want to roll back to manual handling of everything.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: I think you can just adapt this for your purpose:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233355/how-can-i-mock-auth0-authentication-for-testing

Answer (score 5):

Try to perform auth in [globalSetup](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-global-setup-teardown#example) function before all test runs, where you perform signup/login actions and save cookies. Works well with auth0 or anything else - perfect for tests with OTP.

**global-setup.ts**

```js
import { chromium, type FullConfig } from '@playwright/test';

async function globalSetup(config: FullConfig) {
  const { baseURL, storageState } = config.projects[0].use;
  const browser = await chromium.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(baseURL!);
  await page.getByLabel('User Name').fill('user');
  await page.getByLabel('Password').fill('password');
  await page.getByText('Sign in').click();
  await page.context().storageState({ path: storageState as string });
  await browser.close();
}

export default globalSetup;
```

**playwright.config.ts**

```js
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';
export default defineConfig({
  globalSetup: require.resolve('./global-setup'),
  use: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    storageState: 'state.json',
  },
});
```

As an option in that function, you can read the cookie creation dateTime and don't run auth if not needed